# How to keep multiple versions of an artifact distinguished by properties in Artifactory?

Tags: versioning, artifactory

is it possible to somehow keep different versions of the same file in Artifactory, where the versions are differentiated by their properties?

For example, let's have a file `foo`.

1. I upload the file to Artifactory via the REST API and set `ver=1` property.
2. The file changes, I upload it again, this time it has `ver=2` property.

Later I try to access the `ver=1` file, but get a 404 error.

I understand that Artifactory keeps different versions of Artifacts which are associated with different builds. However there is no build info other than the "custom property" for the files I am uploading. How can I version them?

Comment: When you upload ver2 of the file, are you overwriting the previous one (ver1)? this will happen if you deploy to the same exact path using the same file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that each artifact is also deployed with a unique path/file name. It is not enough to have a different set of properties.
Usually the best way to version the file will be having the version number as part of the file name and possibly also as part of the path.